# Texture shaking/trembling in Blender Game Engine

Tags: texturing, game-engine

In trying to simulate a first person camera in the Blender Game Engine, I have hit a snag.

Kindly open the attached blend file and hit P to run a (very simple) demo of a first person camera (sitting atop a red cube moving across a deformed plane).

You will see that the textures of the plane (upon which a small cube is moving) shake and tremble a bit before settling down (?) every time the cube is moved.

W and S move the cube forth and back, the left and right cursor keys turn the cube.

If I try to run the test game from another view (not through the camera), there is no trembling of the texture of the plane. The problem only appears when I hit number pad zero to enter camera view and then hit P to run the game engine.

Can you help me correct this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use UV-Mapping (Properties / Texture / Mapping / Coordinates). It indeed means you need to setup UV-Coordinates beforehand.

There is an additional flickering that comes from shadows. I suggest to have a look at the shadow settings too.

Comment: Thank you very much as well! UN unwrapping the plane solved the texture problem, even when the camera was rotated at 90 degrees! I did see the problem with the shadows flickering too, but I am not sure how to tinker with shadow settings. In the render properties panel of the BGE, under GSLS, I can only turn shadows on or off. Should I play with the settings in the texture panel? Your further help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is less flickering when I select variance rather than simple buffer type in the shadows section of the Sun properties panel, but I am not sure what I should change beyond that.

Comment: I'm glad to help you. I can't tell about the shadows (I just switched them off and the flickering disappeared). You might post a separate question regarding shadows.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really strange issue and I was able to replicate it with different textures and objects. I don't know why it happens but if you want to fix it rotate the camera a little bit on the X Axis. Just select the camera, press R then X.
It looks like the problem only appears when the rotation is 90°.

Comment: Thank you very much! Rotating the camera to a value different than 90 degrees, e.g. 91 degrees, solved the problem!